# Capitalizing a string

Tags: beginner, strings, haskell

I wrote the following function that takes a string and returns a new string with each word capitalized: first letter uppercase, following letters lower-cased.

It works, but I would be interested in seeing how a more sophisticated Haskell programmer would do this (if there is already a built-in, great, but still interested in an example implementation).

```
ghci> let capWord word = [toUpper $ head word] ++ (map toLower $ tail word)
ghci> let capitalize sentence = unwords $ map capWord $ words sentence
ghci> capitalize "the quick brown fox jUMPS OVER thE LaZY DOG"
"The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog"
```

Comment: FIY, I asked a question concerning the `capitalize` function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222013/how-to-abstract-over-a-back-and-forth-transformation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`head` and `tail` are [partial functions](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Partial_functions), meaning that they are only defined for non-empty lists and will fail on empty ones. Because of this your `capWord` function is also partial and its strongly considered a bad practice to define such functions. In fact, the `head` and `tail` are also considered a bad heritage and in [some alternative preludes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/classy-prelude) it's been deliberately decided not to export such functions. So, firstly, you can redefine your function with pattern matching and make it total.

Secondly, you're introducing a redundant list for the first letter, instead you can prepend it using the `:` (pronounced "cons") operator.

Summing up we get the following definition:

```
capWord [] = []
capWord (h:t) = toUpper h : map toLower t
```

Alternatively (essentially the same):

```
capWord word = case word of
  [] -> []
  (h:t) -> toUpper h : map toLower t
```

The `capitalize` function is fine.

Comment: Thanks, I read up on partial functions, and how to avoid them http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Avoiding_partial_functions.

Comment: `words` will never return an empty string, so making `capWord` local to capitalize would also be okay. But since `capWord` is also useful on it's own, your solution is best.